# Print full data of char* pointer?

Tags: c++, leveldb

I'm new in C++ and I want to show data of char* pointer before writing it to file but the output only 5 first bytes. I don't know what is wrong with it. I'm using __android_log_print to show log.

This is code to write data to file :

[image]

Logcat show :

> WriteUnbuffered filename = /data/user/0/com.abc.helloleveldb/databases/leveldb/000003.log
>
> WriteUnbuffered  size = 37 ,data before encrypt = ��� -> only 5bytes .

but data write to the full file, 2 pairs of data ( test: okok and test1: hello)

[image]

If your have any suggest , please help me. Thank you

Comment: `%d` is incorrect format specifier for `size`, this causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M I dont see any problem with size.

Comment: Well there is a problem and I have pointed it out and it would be a good idea to fix it

Comment: @M.M thank you. I changed %d to %zu.

Comment: `"%s"` expects a null-terminated string.  Is your data null-terminated?  If not, you should refrain from using any C-string functions that rely on null-terminated buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the buffer at `data` looks to be binary data and is unsuitable for to pass in for a `%s` format.

I would suggest iterating through every char (byte) individually and logging the hex value instead, something like this:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<size; ++i) {
    LOGD("WriteUnbuffered data[%zu]=0x%02x", i, (data[i])&0xff);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help , I tried to print hex but it just numbers like this :

WriteUnbuffered data[0]=0xad , string = 173
WriteUnbuffered data[1]=0x46 , string = 70
WriteUnbuffered data[2]=0xd4 , string = 212
WriteUnbuffered data[3]=0x20 , string = 32
WriteUnbuffered data[4]=0x1e , string = 30
WriteUnbuffered data[5]=0x00 , string = 0
WriteUnbuffered data[6]=0x01 , string = 1
....

Comment: Do you have any idea if I want to encrypt char *data?

Comment: @thanhlv values like 0x20, 0x1e, are the byte values stored in the buffer.  If you know what the meaning of those byte values is, you should be able to interpret the output.  It's not clear why you are sending the buffer to the LOG.  I also cannot answer whether you want to encrypt the data.  Your question was just about how to log all of the bytes of the buffer.